# Text editor quotation mark woes

Tags: text-editor

In text editor my quotation marks keep getting replaced by non ascii versions.

So if I am editing an XML document the double vertical line type quotation mark keeps getting auto-replaced by the curly type that breaks the XML document.

I have turned off the Text replacement option in preferences but it keeps happening.

Comment: Is the text editor you are using `TextEdit` or another one? Please add this key information within your original question (and not within comments which fate is to disappear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using TextEdit, go to Preferences > New Document > Options and uncheck the box for smart quotes:

[image: TextEdit preferences]

You may then require a system restart.